# Do bitcoin exchanges based outside of the US who serve US customers have to register with FinCEN as MSBs?

Tags: exchanges, mtgox, legal, bitstamp, fincen

From what I understand, Bitstamp is not registered with FinCEN, whereas Mt.Gox is, does this mean Bitstamp is in danger of being shut down?

Answer (score 1):

The short (slightly oversimplified) answer is that most consumer protection oriented laws (including Money Services Business and Money Transmitter laws) apply to the **consumers** themselves. So if you serve customers in the US, you must comply with the laws that protect those customers.

IANAL, YMMV, etc. Consult an attorney specializing in MSB/Money Transmitter laws for an more accurate application of the laws to your business model.

Comment: Thanks, can Bitstamp legally service US customers then if they don't have a Money Service Business licence?